# How to use culture for changing the datetime format

Tags: asp.net

I want to change the date format

```
CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("en-US");

Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;

string fromdate =(TxtFrom.Text);

string todate = (TxtTo.Text);

DateTime dt =DateTime.Parse(fromdate);

DateTime d =DateTime.Parse(todate);

_DivAPath.FROM_DATE = Convert.ToDateTime("d",ci);

_DivAPath.TO_DATE = Convert.ToDateTime("d",ci);
```

But it will show exception that the given Datetime is not a correct format.how to change the datetime function...

please explain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you don't need to actually change the culture if you want to parse or convert dates with a given `CultureInfo`, so this is unnecessary:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
```

You can simply use the [`DateTime.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kc8s65zs.aspx) overload that accepts the culture:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(fromdate, ci);
```

---

The exception is probably raised at `Convert.ToDateTime("d",ci);` since `d` is not a valid date ;)

Maybe `FROM_DATE` is a string property and you actually want to convert the datetime to a short-date-string, then you could either use:

```
_DivAPath.FROM_DATE = dt.ToString("d", ci);
```

or

```
_DivAPath.FROM_DATE = dt.ToShortDateString(); // uses the current-culture
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the String `"d"` as a value to convert to DateTime. Pass `d` and `dt` without the quotation marks.

Comment: So why should he use `Convert.ToDateTime` on a `DateTime` variable at all?